# Drupal + Zen - not proper layout/no graphics

Tags: php, web-server, website, drupal

I installed Drupal (both using Fantastico, then started over from scratch) and Drupal works great except when I setup the Zen theme (following the instructions on the website and in the readme-first.txt) the theme does not show up properly.

it has no graphics except for the tiny drupal logo way at the bottom.

the rest is text.

I have uploaded the theme to the /public_html/sites/all/themes folder and it does show up in themes in the administer section so I select enable and default. permissions on this folder are 755.

any ideas?

I checked the Drupal forums and someone is having the same problem but no one replied (this was in April) so I figured I would have a better shot on this awesome website.

thanks.

Luma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like Firebug (Firefox extension) or check to source-code to see what URL the HTML is looking for. May be that something is slightly different with the Fantastico file layout. Once you know the URL to the images, use them directly to see what you get. If you get a Drupal error page you know your files are in the wrong place. Then its a question to change Zen configuration or the directories.

Alternatively do a manual install of Drupal and Zen and see if you get a different result.